# Configure Azure DevOps email template

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have configured **Microsoft Azure DevOps** to build our software and release it automatically. (With the Build and with the release Pipeline) 
After the succesful release I have set it up, to send an email to all project-members.

**My question is: Can I somehow configure this email?**

E.g. I need to remove the "Summary" part. Is this somehow possible with Azure Devops?

Screenshot of current email:

[image: screenshot of email]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, currently you can't configure the email templates. there is a popular [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365760/customize-vsts-email-templates.html) about it, you can up vote there.

As workaround, you can install the [Send Email](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask) task, and add it to the release pipeline, in this task you can customize the email.

Comment: It works only in Windows Agents

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old. However, I've been able to modify the email template for standard check-ins.

The TeamFoundation.xsl in the Program Files\Azure**\Application Tier\TFSJobAgent\Transforms\1033 folder is the file to modify. It doesn't take affect immediately. I noted the changes after a server reboot.